# Joomla Search issue ".com/index.php/component/users/?view=reset"

Tags: templates, joomla

I am using Joomla for my website when I search in google for SAPBuddy I always get search result.
Can some one help me I tried to add my side in Google webmaster, but the result is same.

sapbuddy.com/index.php/component/users/?view=reset

Comment: You don't explain the problem. And is there a question here?

Answer (score 0):

Check you've followed these steps.

1. Create a sitemap. You can use an [online tool for this](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com), or a [Joomla extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/site-map)
2. If you used an online tool to create your sitemap, upload the site the xml file to your server. If you're using an extension, follow their direction. When finished, you should be able to open it with your web browser, e.g. www.domain.com/sitemap.xml . Check if the indexed pages looke good and copy this URL
3. In webmaster tooks, add your domain then register this sitemap, pasting in your URL
4. After a short period, check back on Webmaster tools. It will show which pages have been indexed and if there were any errors.

Good luck!